# Iterate through a list and check each element with your own condition?

Tags: list, loops, if-statement, syntax, common-lisp

For an homework, I am trying to iterate through the list and make an if statement to each of the elements I encounter in Common Lisp.
Most of my problems come from me not knowing the syntax very well though.

Here is what I am trying to do:

`*lst*` is for example `(1 4 2 6 4 7 2 4)`

```
(setq finalList())

(loop for x in lst                      

    (if ((< x 5) && (not(equal(x nil))))       ; IF x < 5 and x != nil

         (append lst x)                        ; THEN STATEMENT

         (princ "Skip")                        ; ELSE STATMENT
     )
```

That logically should have done it, however, I am possibly wrong with my syntax
(If I forgot extra colon here, judge if as pseudo code, thanks)

**How to iterate through the list and make an *if else* statements to each of the elements I encounter?**

Comment: note that your question is about the Common Lisp the language, not CLISP a Common Lisp implementation.

Comment: You are on the right path with using `loop`. However it is a `macro` and it has special syntax, thus you can't just insert s-expressions in it's "body" and expect it to work. Some people would even say that the `loop` and `format` facilities are a complete languages in their own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Errors

1. Syntax: instead of infix `&&`, you need prefix [`and`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_and.htm)
2. [`loop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_loop.htm) requires the keyword [`do`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_ae.htm) before the [`if`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_if.htm) form.
3. [`append`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_append.htm) is non-destructive, so if you did not assign its return value to a variable, you did nothing.
4. Lisp function call syntax is `(func arg1 arg2 ...)` and not `(func (arg1 arg2 ...))` as you use in your `equal` call.
5. The order of conditionals matters: if `x` is `nil`, then `(< x 5)` will signal an error, so you need to check `x` before the comparison.
6. The long and complicated `(not (equal x nil))` is actually equivalent to `x`.
7. Unlike in other languages (e.g., C and Python), in Lisp parens matter, e.g., `foo`, `(foo)`, `((foo))` are three very different things and can never be used interchangeably.

## Solutions

### Use the Loop micro-language

The [`loop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_loop.htm) facility is perfect as it has the [`if`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_af.htm) and [`collect`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_ac.htm) clauses:

```
(loop for x in lst
   if (and x (< x 5))
   then collect x
   else (print x))
```

Note: this does not really look like Lisp, so you might want to steer clear of loop while you are learning the language.

### Use Functional Programming

```
(remove-if-not (lambda (x) (and x (< x 5))) lst)
```

Note: this does not print the dropped elements, I am sure you had the `print` clause for debugging only anyway.

### Use Iteration

```
(let ((res ()))
  (dolist (x lst (nreverse res))
    (when (and x (< x 5))
      (push x res))))
```

Note: I use [`nreverse`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_revers.htm): since we construct the result list ourselves, the is no reason not to use the destructive version or `reverse`.

Comment: Sir, you just solved all my problems from this task!
Thank you very much!